# Can you save an image that you used imagecopyresized() on to MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, gd, thumbnails

I've been trying multiple ways to try to make thumbnails for my photo gallery, but since I couldn't find a way to resize a picture while it was a BLOB, I decided to try to save it to MySQL as a BLOB of its own. However it won't let me save it and gives me nothing when I echo it. Any ideas how I could save it to MySQL?

```
$tmp_img = imagecreatetruecolor($tw,$th);
imagecopyresized($tmp_img, $im, 0, 0, 0, 0, $tw, $th, $size[0],$size[1]);
ob_start();
imagejpeg($tmp_img);
$i=ob_get_clean();
$fp=fopen($nar,'w');
fwrite($fp,$i);
fclose($fp);
$filename_thumb=addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['nar']));
mysql_query("INSERT INTO photos (filename,caption,album,thumbl) 
VALUES ('" . $filename . "','" . $caps . "','" . $_POST['albums'] . "','" .  
$filename_thumb . "')") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: I'd suggest storing the images on disk using a guid as a filename in the DB. Also have you looked at imagecreatefromstring(), you may have to resort to output buffering to re-capture the final image data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$tmp_img` isn't a filename, it's an GD image resource. You have to write an image from it by using one of [`imagejpeg()`](http://php.net/imagejpeg), [`imagepng()`](http://php.net/imagepng) or [`imagegif()`](http://php.net/imagegif).

You can use a temporary file or the [output buffer](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) to store the image data.

Comment: @AndreKR, I edited the question with what I tried, but it still didn't work, see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What are you trying to do in lines 6-8? Just delete them and replace `file_get_contents($_FILES['nar'])` with `$i`.

Comment: @AndreKR Thanks that worked, sorry about that other fopen() stuff, the example I found showed that and whenever I looked up fopen() it seemed like I'd need it. Thanks alot :D

Comment: @AndreKR sorry to keep bothering you, for some reason the images are turning up completely black. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Maybe some problem with imagecopyresized. I'd suggest you post another question showing the code that makes `$im` and giving a `var_dump()` of `$size`, `$th` and `$tw`. It can help to put one such image online for download.